# Can the head of a list in prolog consist of multiple elements?

Tags: list, prolog

For example if I have a list `[1, 2| 3]`, would the head be `1`, `2` and the tail `3`? Or would the head still be `1` and the tail `2, 3`?

Answer (score 2):

> **Note**: `[1, 2| 3]` is *not* a list; `[1, 2 | [3]]` is.

**Short answer**: there is only **one element in the head**, `[1, 2| [3]]` is syntactical sugar for `[1 | [2 | [3]]]`, so it is a list `[1, 2, 3]`.

Prolog's lists are like Lisp lists: they consist out of two possible values: an empty list `[]`, and a "cons" `[H|T]` with `H` the *head, and `T` the *tail*.

Most Prolog interpreters will however allow syntactical sugar like `[E1, E2, E3]` and `[E1, E2, E3 | T]`. to make it more convient to do list processing.